# How can I troubleshoot error 10049?

Tags: networking, internet, troubleshooting

We have an multi-tier application that lets our clients connect through the internet to us and have run into an interesting problem recently.  From some client locations, User A will attempt to connect to our service and get error [10049 (cannot find address)](http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WSK-19980701-EM04.htm), while user B will attempt to connect using the same application, public IP, and settings and get through just fine.  Normally, the client application is run from inside an internal network local to the client.  Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer this morning.  Apparently, the powers that be decided to switch off our old T1 connection last week and switch on the new cable connection for users to connect.  Because of this, the users who had newer versions of the client application were able to connect just fine, while the users who had older versions were not able to connect.  I maintain connection information historically so if one address fails, then another gets tried, and the new IP wasn't set up until recently, so the older versions didn't get it.  The bottom line is that the older versions didn't know about the new IP so were not able to connect.